# Gulp task utilizando (usemin)

Tags: javascript, gulp, task

Comecei recentemente a utilizar o Gulp, em um projeto já existente. Criei o seguinte `gulpfile.js`:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    htmlReplace = require('gulp-html-replace'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    usemin = require('gulp-usemin'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');

gulp.task('default', ['copy'], function(){
    gulp.start('build-img', 'usemin');
});

gulp.task('copy', ['clean'], function(){
    return gulp.src('src/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function(){
    return gulp.src('dist')
        .pipe(clean());    
});

gulp.task('build-img', function(){
    gulp.src('dist/img/*/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));    
});

gulp.task('usemin', function(){
    gulp.src('dist/**/*.html')
        .pipe(usemin({
            'js' : [uglify],
            'css': [cssmin]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
 });
```

Funciona corretamente, porém gostaria de saber qual é o procedimento para que nas pastas `dist/css` e `dist/js`, todas as pastas e arquivos sejam apagados e fiquem somente os arquivos `index.min.css` e `index.min.js` que o `usemin()` gerou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quatro passos:

**PASSO 1:** Instalar o [pacote del do npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del):

```
npm install --save del
```

> Passos seguintes alteram o seu arquivo do Gulp (exemplo: gulpfile.js)

**PASSO 2:** incluir o comando `del`:

```
del    = require('del');
```

**PASSO 3:** criar uma tarefa para excluir:

```
gulp.task('tarefa_que_deleta', function () {
      return del([
           'dist//css/**',
           'dist//js/**'
        ]);
});
```

**PASSO 4:** chamar a tarefa (exemplo abaixo colocando ela para ser executada sempre que seu script GULP for iniciado, dentro de `default`):

```
gulp.task('default', ['copy', 'tarefa_que_deleta'], function(){
    gulp.start('build-img', 'usemin');
});
```

**Resultado:**
Vai ser algo mais ou menos assim:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    htmlReplace = require('gulp-html-replace'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    usemin = require('gulp-usemin'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin'),
    del    = require('del');

gulp.task('default', ['copy', 'tarefa_que_deleta'], function(){
    gulp.start('build-img', 'usemin');
});

gulp.task('copy', ['clean'], function(){
    return gulp.src('src/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function(){
    return gulp.src('dist')
        .pipe(clean());    
});

gulp.task('tarefa_que_deleta', function () {
      return del([
           'dist//css/**',
           'dist//js/**'
        ]);
});

gulp.task('build-img', function(){
    gulp.src('dist/img/*/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));    
});

gulp.task('usemin', function(){
    gulp.src('dist/**/*.html')
        .pipe(usemin({
            'js' : [uglify],
            'css': [cssmin]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
 });
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado @Allan Andrade